# Поменять переменную вида categoryid на categoryID с помощью htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть задача заменить в урлах с GET-переменными одну переменную на другую (разница только в регистре символов). Для одиночной страницы это выглядит так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^categoryid=418$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.site.ru/index.php?categoryID=418 [R=301,L]
```

Как записать правило для любого номера категории, с учетом того, что в строке могут быть и другие переменные после `categoryID`?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)categoryid=([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1categoryID=%2%3 [R=301,L]
```

Из `%{QUERY_STRING}` нужно захватить все данные, чтобы передать их правильно в редирект. В группу `%1` попадает начало `%{QUERY_STRING}` до переменной `categoryid`, в группу `%2` попадает содержимое переменной `categoryid`, а в группу `%3` окончание `%{QUERY_STRING}`.

Здесь `/index.php?%1categoryID=%2%3` все они возвращаются на свои места с заменой `categoryid=` на `categoryID=`.